# jQuery Date Picker with the TimePicker addon hours slider

Tags: jquery

I'm using Trent Richardson's timepicker add-on for JQ DatePicker.
http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Is there a way to have the hours slider display a 12 hour clock and AM or PM?

This is the init I'm using:

```
$('#date_xmas_eve_open').datetimepicker({
    pickerTimeFormat: 'H:mm TT', 
    onClose: UpdateXmasEveOpen
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this resource (very useful for JS times\dates and common formats): http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

I believe the format you want is like this:

```
$('#date_xmas_eve_open').datetimepicker({
    pickerTimeFormat: 'h:MM TT', 
    onClose: UpdateXmasEveOpen
});
```

Hope this helps.